# Runtime 1004 error saving to C drive

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook, with several worksheets in it. Each worksheet is a document I would like to email separately.

I have the workbook on a Windows XP SP3 machine running Office 2007. The VBA code works perfectly, and I can email each individual worksheet.

I need to run this on a Windows 7 or Windows 10 PC, again with Office 2007. This is where I get the error:

[image: 1004 error]

```
Sub EmailWithOutlook()
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oMail As Object
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wSht As Worksheet
    Dim shtName As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Make a copy of the active worksheet
    ' and save it to a temporary file
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

    FileName = WB.Worksheets(1).Name
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill "C:\" & FileName
    On Error GoTo 0
    WB.SaveAs FileName:="C:\" & FileName

    'Create and show the Outlook mail item
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
    With oMail
        'Uncomment the line below to hard code a recipient
        '.To = "testuser@test.com"
        'Uncomment the line below to hard code a subject
        '.Subject = "Subject Line"
        'Uncomment the lines below to hard code a body
        '.body = "Dear John" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
          '"Here is the file you asked for"
        .Attachments.Add WB.FullName
        .Display
    End With

    'Delete the temporary file
    WB.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
    Kill WB.FullName
    WB.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'Restore screen updating and release Outlook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The routine stops on the line containing the following:
`WB.SaveAs FileName:="C:\" & FileName`

What am I missing?

Comment: It might be user account control. Try saving to the path of the current workbook instead to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows users by default do not have permission to write at `C:\` root directory.

Solutions:

- Use a sub directory where the user has permission to write
- Change user permission to gain write access at `C:\` (not recommended)